# Geometry Dash won't start, linked to libcocos2d.dll file

Tags: geometry-dash

Whenever I try to launch Geometry Dash through Steam or through the executable file itself, the game fails to run, and no window appears. It had run fine for a while, and one day it simply wouldn't start anymore. Reinstalling the game and restarting Steam/my computer doesn't help anything.  Upon checking Event Viewer it shows this error in Windows Logs:

```
Faulting application name: GeometryDash.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x54be1cbd
Faulting module name: libcocos2d.dll, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x54be1c97
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000e4e10
Faulting process id: 0xd6c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0464a42a17798
Faulting application path: D:\Steam\steamapps\common\Geometry Dash\GeometryDash.exe
Faulting module path: D:\Steam\steamapps\common\Geometry Dash\libcocos2d.dll
Report Id: 81290111-b23d-11e4-a153-485b39f272a2
```

Geometry Dash cannot run without the libcocos2d.dll file, which I believe is the file causing the error. Is there any way to correct this? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried verifying your game cache?

Comment: I have, the game still failed to start. @aytimothy

Comment: Have you tried running the game as an administrator? (`0xc0000005` means an Access Violation; no read-write permissions) | You may want to look at [this MS Windows documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx), which tells you what your exception (exit) codes mean.

Comment: @aytimothy Running GeometryDash.exe as an administrator returns the same error and error code.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem (whit "libcocos2d.dll") is solved by installing the optimal driver for your video card.

Here's a video (in spanish) where I show that I have the problem with "libcocos2d.dll" and this is corrected by installing the correct video driver.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the folder causing this issue when I tried to move data from my computer to my laptop. The folder C:\Users(user)\AppData\Local\GeometryDash contains at least one file that was causing the game to fail to load. I don't know which file this is, but deleting the folder (causing the game to reinstall it) allowed the game to run again, just without my old data.

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete the file `fronts` from the folder of Geometry Dash resources folder in the Geometry Dash folder then click `geometry dash.exe` in the Geometry Dash folder and the game will open.

It seems that the game doubles the fonts and can't run or something like that and you have to delete the folder `fonts`.

Answer (score -1):

you have to delete the file fronts from the folder of geometry dash resorces folder in the geometry dash folder then click geometry dash exe. in the geometrydash folder and the game will open.